# Selecting the closest match from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a database of clothing sizes, the user inputs their measurements and it returns a match, if there is no match it returns a list the closest matches to their users details.

What I want to do, is if there is no perfect match, show the match which is the closest to their measurements.

This is my query to get the matches.

```
 SELECT * FROM sizing where bust_cm like '$bust%' AND waist_cm like '$waist%' AND hips_cm like '$hips%'
```

however the best match could be the correct size on two but just one or two digits over on the third and so i am trying to find the best way to calculate which of the results matched the best.

Comment: Instead of `$bust%` try `%$bust%` or you can check [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: @RobinSingh W3School is a _terrible_ site for SQL related stuff.  It was created for HTML, CSS, and maybe JavaScript, not SQL.

Comment: I am not asking to test the code, i refer this just to read the description

Comment: Thanks Robin, I tried that previously and found if it matches on one value the other two can be out and not making it the best across all three values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the measurements in your table really strings?

If they are numeric values, you might want to look at doing it by finding rows with the minimum difference between the database values and your inputs.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sizing
ORDER BY (ABS(bust_cm - $bust) + ABS(waist_cm - $waist) + ABS(hips_cm - $hips)) ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried that.  The user input values are 86, 63, 95  using the above the code brings back 78, 60, 86.  show all the results using the original code the best matching is 86, 60, 94 but i can't get the code to pick that value as the closest match

Comment: Ah ok. Good. I've used logic like this quite a bit. If any on the measurements are more significant than others you can add scaling factors - e.g.
    ...
    ORDER BY (ABS(bust_cm - $bust)*$bustFactor + ABS(waist_cm - $waist)*$waistFactor + ABS(hips_cm - $hips)*$hips_factor) ASC

Anyways, glad to help